# Qt C++ Creating toolbar

Tags: c++, qt, toolbar

I am learning Qt and trying some examples in the book "Foundations of Qt Development".
In the book, there is a section teaching Single Document Interface with an example creating a simple app like a notepad.
However I am having problem with toolbar creating.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    setWindowTitle(QString("%1[*] - %2").arg("unnamed").arg("SDI"));

    connect(ui->docWidget->document(), SIGNAL(modificationChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(setWindowModified(bool)));

    createActions();
    createMenu();
    createToolbars();

    statusBar()->showMessage("Done");    
}
```

It is the constructor of the main window.

```
void MainWindow::createToolbars()
{
    QToolBar* toolbar;
    toolbar = addToolBar(tr("File"));
    toolbar->addAction(anyaction);
}
```

This is how the book create the toolbar.
However, when I try to run the program, there are two toolbars created.
One is the toolbar created by the code and called "File"
Another is a blank toolbar created by the ui designer ie. `*ui.toolbar`.

In order to get rid of two toolbars, I tried using only the `*ui.toolbar`.
It's working. The code is shown below.

```
void MainWindow::createToolbars()
{
    ui->toolBar->addAction(anyaction);
}
```

But I tried to create the toolbar by code only, ie. not adding a toolbar in the ui designer.
So I write this:

```
void MainWindow::createToolbars()
{
    QToolBar* FileBar = this->addToolBar(tr("File"));
    FileBar->addAction(anyaction);
}
```

However, there is a compile error.
The compiler use this function:

```
void QMainWindow::addToolBar(QT::ToolBarArea area, QToolBar * toolbar)
```

instead of what I want:

```
QToolBar * QMainWindow::addToolBar(const QString & title)
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#addToolBar-3

What is my mistake here?

Comment: What is a message for compile error?

Comment: @MikhailZimka error: C2027: use of undefined type 'QToolBar'; error: C2227: left of '->addAction' must point to class/struct/union/generic type.  Should be due to `addToolBar(const QString &)` not returning `QToolBar*`

Comment: It is strange a bit, but you can try to explicitly #include <QToolBar> to your source file

Comment: @MikhailZimka It does make the program working if I add `#include <QToolBar>`. Qt Creator shows me that I am using 'void QMainWindow::addToolBar(QT::ToolBarArea area, QToolBar * toolBar)` when the mouse cursor hover around the function. But I check that it is incorrect. I checked there is a return address from `addToolBar()`. So the problem is actually because the `addAction()` cannot be load if `<QToolBar>` is not included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you removed `QToolBar` from `MainWindow` QtCreator automatically removed import of `QToolBar` class.

Just add this to the top of `mainwindow.h`:

```
#include <QToolBar>
```

And it is better to define `QToolBar* FileBar` in `private` section of `MainWindow` in `mainwindow.h`. Then you will be able to access it from any method of `MainWindow` class.

```
void MainWindow::createToolbars()
{
    FileBar = this->addToolBar(tr("File"));
    FileBar->addAction(anyaction);
}
```

When you see such message:

> must point to class/struct/union/generic type

First of all try to include headers for necessary class.

Comment: QtCreator is an IDE. It doesn't do anything like that. You're talking about *uic*  - it takes the `.ui` file and generates the `ui_MainWindow.h`.